# Transfer files from my old SD card to a new one

Tags: usb, sd-card

Totally lost on this. I accidentally fried my pi by connecting the wires on a Motor driver the wrong way round! So, new PI and as I didn't update Raspbian I had to download Noobs to a new card. Up and running now however my son and I have created many files on the old card and we can't transfer them. I have looked at Win32diskimager but I don't want the old Raspbian, we just get a multi-coloured screen. I have a Card Reader and have inserted it into a usb slot on the Pi but can't see any of the files and Windows Explorer doesn't help either. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear what you had or want to recover. If you installed Raspbian to a new SD Card and boot to Desktop and insert the old card in the reader you should be able to copy them. They will be mounted in /media/sdaN where N probably be will 7. You should be able to see them in File Manager. If you provide more detail people could be more specific. Windows Explorer can't read the files - you need to do this on a Linux machine.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of this commands to it: `lsblk` and `findmnt` when you have attached the card reader with SD Card at the RasPi.

Comment: I've tried looking through all the folders. I'm looking for python programs written with Leafpad and some scratch ones my son did. Thank you for your prompt reply.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know where your files are stored and you have two rpi units or an rpi + a Linux/[Windows] computer, you can transfer your files from your rpi to another rpi and/or a computer using `scp` as follows (assuming you already login into the destination device):

1. Recursively copy and/or transfer all files in a sub-directory, i.e. `scp -r [owner]@[IP Address of source rpi]:/[source full path directory]/[sub-directory] /[destination full path directory]`, or
2. Copy and/or transfer a single file, i.e. `scp [owner]@[IP Address of source rpi]:/[source full path directory]/[filename] /[destination full path directory]`

where:

`[owner]` is the login user that owns the file(s). You can also use `root` account.

`[IP Address of source rpi]` is the IP Address assigned to your rpi device that holds the file(s) you want to transfer from.

`/[source full path directory]/[sub-directory]` If the sub-directory where you want to transfer is located in `/tmp/my_subdir` on your rpi where you want to transfer from, then your `/[source full path directory]/[sub-directory]` is `/tmp/my_subdir`.

`/[destination full path directory]` This is the full path where you want to copy and/or transfer your file(s) to your destination rpi/computer. For instance, if you want your `[sub-directory]` and/or `[filename]` from your source rpi to copy/transfer to destination so that they will reside in `/usr/tmp` directory, then they both will be `/usr/tmp`.

To give you a Minimal Working Example (MWE). I want to copy this `/mnt/rpi0/devel/LaTEX/images/ifpdf/CMakeLists` file on my rpi0 (IP Address: 192.168.1.111) to `/usr/tmp` on my Linux computer. So, I login into my Linux computer and execute this `scp rpi0@192.168.1.111:/mnt/rpi0/devel/LaTEX/images/ifpdf/CMakeLists /usr/tmp` to copy and/or transfer the `/mnt/rpi0/devel/LaTEX/images/ifpdf/CMakeLists` on my rpi0 to `/usr/tmp` directory on my Linux computer. If I already change my current working directory (CWD) into `/usr/tmp` while on my Linux (destination) computer, then I can use the `.` instead of `/usr/tmp` to represent the CWD, i.e. `scp rpi0@192.168.1.111:/mnt/rpi0/devel/LaTEX/images/ifpdf/CMakeLists .`

For more information on `scp`, please read its manpage. On your rpi and/or a Linux computer, just execute `man scp` to read the `scp` manpage.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Blimy, think the above will test me! I will give it a go though. Thank you for the prompt and comprehensive reply! Really appreciated. Sorry for the delay in responding too, been on the road.

Comment: Let's us know how it goes. If you need more help, please feel free to ask.